# Color changing bmp in c

Tags: c, binary, bmp

I have a pixel information array who has the biSizeImage size and contains triplets of the form (blue, green, red) with values ​​between 0 and 255. I must change my bmp color from red, to white, but i have a problem, as can be seen in picture.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{ 
BITMAPFILEHEADER file;
BITMAPINFOHEADER info;
FILE* f=fopen("imagine.bmp","rb");
fread(&file,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,f);
fread(&info,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,f);
RGBQUAD *a=malloc(info.biSizeImage*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
fread(a,sizeof(RGBQUAD),info.biSizeImage,f);
for(int i=0;i<info.biSizeImage;i++)
  {
      a[i].rgbBlue=255;
      a[i].rgbGreen=255;
      a[i].rgbRed=255;
  }
FILE* f2=fopen("imagine2.bmp","wb");
if(f2==NULL)
    printf("Error");
fwrite(&file,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,f2);
fwrite(&info,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,f2);
fwrite(a,sizeof(RGBQUAD),info.biSizeImage,f2);
return 0;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC8fO.png)

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldbxg.png)

Comment: Have you forgotten about stride? The size of each row of pixel data in a bmp image must be a multiple of 4 bytes, which means there are 0 to 3 padding bytes at the end of each row.

Comment: Can you give me an example, for my code if you can?

Comment: Ah, you should look up the bmp definition, but now you have posted the image links, I suggest you look at `sizeof(RGBQUAD)` which is not 3 but 4. Are there 24 or 32 bits per pixel?

Comment: 24 bits per pixel

Comment: So there is your answer.

Comment: So, i must change my array size with a stride, where stride = ( bits per row +31)/32 *4?

Comment: You must get the stride right, and you must write to sets of 3 bytes, not 4. You are writing to 3 bytes, then skipping one, then to the next 3 and so on. An easy way to do that you be to have an array of `unsigned char` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`info.biSizeImage` can be zero. Check to make sure it is not zero, or calculate it based on stride. Width, height, and bitcount values are always set.

As noted in comments, 24 bit image has 3 bytes (24 bit) per pixel. `RGBQUA` is for 32-bit image. You have to iterate through the height, and then width 3 bytes at a time.

```
int main(void)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER file;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info;
    FILE* f = fopen("imagine.bmp", "rb");
    fread(&file, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f);
    fread(&info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, f);
    if(info.biBitCount != 24)
        return 0;

    int stride = ((info.biWidth * info.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4;
    int size = stride * info.biHeight;
    BYTE *a = malloc(stride * info.biHeight);
    fread(a, 1, size, f);
    for(int y = info.biHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < stride; x += 3)
        {
            int i = y * stride + x;
            a[i + 0] = 255;
            a[i + 1] = 255;
            a[i + 2] = 255;
        }
    }

    FILE* f2 = fopen("imagine2", "wb");
    if(f2 == NULL)
        printf("Error");
    fwrite(&file, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f2);
    fwrite(&info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, f2);
    fwrite(a, 1, size, f2);
    return 0;
}
```